# How can an optical signal be transduced to an audio/mechanical signal without using electricity?

Tags: optics, acoustics, material-science, optical-materials

There are several ways to directly convert acoustic/mechanic signals into optic signals (e.g. opening/closing a shutter, or the [acousto-optic effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acousto-optics#Acousto-optic_effect)). Is there any way to do the reverse, without using photoelectric effects or other electric effects/electricity as intermediate?

I suppose one way would be to use the thermal heating from the light to deform e.g. a bimetal, but I doubt that will work with the light intensity of fiber-optic signals and it would probably be limited to low frequencies. Or am I wrong with that?

edit: background: This is purely theoretical. I'm exploring what the world would look like if we did not use electricity. While the acousto-optic  effect can modulate sound onto a laser beam, I haven't found a way to do the reverse except by using electrical components.

Comment: Would a crystal radio satisfy your restrictions? Perhaps not since electricity is involved. How about a piezo sensor launching a surface wave? Or is the piezo effect considered electricity? Of course, a high enough power laser creates audible effects when it hits somethng. What are your real constraints? What are you really trying to do?

Comment: I don't really understand your examples.  How is opening/closing a shutter going from mechanical to optic signals?  Closing a shutter based on light would likely require some electronics to start the circuit and some sort of actuating device.  Your acoustio-optic effect seems to also use electricity.

Comment: Use film as an amplifier: expose a moving strip of film to record the modulation, develop it, now run that film under a powerful light (such as the sun) which can for instance heat a bimetallic strip.  You may want several stages of amplification, but this is easy enough to do.

Comment: @JMac By opening/closing a shutter you can send on/off keyed messages by light, e.g. morse code. My question is about going the other way, e.g. if sound is encoded in the intensity of a laser, how to get the sound back.
The acousto-optic effect is that the refractive index of some materials change if pressure is applied to them. The link is to an acousto-optic modulator that first uses a piezo to transform an electric input to pressure.

Comment: @JMac Google for "Aldis Lamp".

Comment: Have you read the $Wiki$ article on the Photoacoustic effect?

Comment: @PhilipWood No, I missed that in my googling. That's exactly the kind of thing I'm looking for. Although it is a bit similar to the method I mentioned in the question, it turns out the photoacoustic effect is a lot more effective than I imagined and can readily be used to [create sound](http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0031-9120/51/4/045015)

Comment: The photoacoustic effect was in fact used by Alexander Graham Bell in his [photophone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photophone) wireless phone design. Though later versions used photoelectric receivers, the first designs used the photoacoustic effect and one was "'painfully loud' to an ear pressed close to the device" (though the wikipedia article doesn't give a source for that quote).

Comment: @JanKanis is your desired answer supposed to be in the realm of human engineering?  The phenomena of [_areo-thermoacoustics_](http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0034-4885/19/1/305/pdf) comes to mind in Earth's atmosphere, similar to your thermal heating / bimetal example.